# How to retrieve array using Symfony $request->getParameter()

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="my_checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="my_checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="my_checkbox[]">
```

In action:

```
$arr= $request->getParameter('my_checkbox[]');
```

This does not work.
Any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
$arr = $request->getParameter('my_checkbox');
```

Comment: yeah this should return an array of values.